# Why FLUIDTEMPLATE variable is not passing to fluid Template html file?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I am trying to pass variables via FLUIDTEMPLATE. But my attempts are miserably failing every time. I have created a simpleblog extension via ext-builder. So I have my template files in **simpleblog/Resources/Private/Templates/Blog/List.html.**  I am using this [basic example](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/9.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#settings) to access data using FLUIDTEMPLATE. I put following code it in my extension's setup.typoscript.

```
page = PAGE
page {
 10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
   
  file = EXT:simpleblog/Resources/Private/Templates/Blog/List.html
  settings {
     copyrightYear = 2013
   }
  }
}
```

and access this in template file as

```
...
<h3>{settings.copyrightYear}</h3>
```

I understand this is simple. But I don't know what's stopping me to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a `FLUIDTEMPLATE`object you can add variables similar to your example. but with the property `variables`:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    file = EXT:simpleblog/Resources/Private/Templates/Blog/List.html
    variables {
        copyrightYear = 2013
   }
}
```

But you are talking about an extension.

Extensions have their own templating without an explicit declaration in typoscript.
The template and the variables are prepared inside the PHP code of the extension (probably the controller).
some variables which often(!) are copied to the fluid are the settings of the plugin. These values could then be found in a fluid variable `setting`.

read the manual of the extension and you will find something like:

```
plugin {
    myextension {
        settings {
            mySetting = myValue
        }
    }
}
```

but that can be different for each extension or plugin, so the path could differ with plugin name instead of extension name or with additional pathes for different actions.

```
plugin {
    myplugin {
        list {
            settings {
                myListSetting = myListValue
            }
        }
        show {
            settings {
                myShowSetting = myShowValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget that these settings might be overriden with values from the plugin content element inside the PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

How do fill the blogs variable? If you already have created an extension, then logic and the settings should be set in plugin.tx_yourext.settings and not in a global scope. I think you’re mixing up some things here. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#typoscript-configuration

Comment: I put the code inside plugin.tx_simpleblog {}. Still I got no variable..